# brew: bash completions broken on macOS

Tags: macos, bash, autocomplete, homebrew

I am using following bash completions installed via brew: `bash-completion` and `bash-completion@2`. My `.bashrc` looks like:

```
if [ -f /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
. /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
fi


if [ -f /usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_2/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  BASH_COMPLETION=/usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_2/etc/bash_completion
  . /usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_2/etc/bash_completion
fi
```

The problem is when I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> on keyboard I get the error:

> -bash: words: bad array subscript

What is the problem here? How can I fix it?

**Update 1:** After removing `/usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion` from `.bashrc` error doesn't happen but I miss out on many completions.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that I should call bash completion from 1.3.2 before `bash-completion@2`. Following is how my `.bashrc` looks, and this solves the problem:

```
if [ -f /usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_2/etc/bash_completion ]; then
  BASH_COMPLETION=/usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_2/etc/bash_completion
  . /usr/local/Cellar/bash-completion/1.3_2/etc/bash_completion
fi

if [ -f /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/local/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The new proper way is add the following line to your ~/.bash_profile::

```
[[ -r "/usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]] && . "/usr/local/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"
```

Comment: The HomeBrew path is different on Silicon macs.  This will work on Intel & Silicon Macs:  `HOMEBREW_PREFIX="$(brew --prefix)";  [[ -r "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh" ]] && source "${HOMEBREW_PREFIX}/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh"`